# Run console command from another one

Tags: php, console, yii2, console-application

How do I run a console controller action from another console controller action?

I've tried the following

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function actionBar()
    {
        $this->run('baz/quux', ['baz'=>'quux']);
    }
}

class BazController extends Controller
{
    public function actionQuux($baz)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error

> Error: Unknown option: --baz

Though the `quux` action of the `baz` controller has the `baz` parameter and running `./yii baz/quux quux` succeeds.

I don't mean to specify an option, I don't even use options. I want to specify the action's parameter. What should be the format of the parameters array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the parameters array should not contain parameter keys... It should look like this

```
$this->run('baz/quux', ['quux']);
```